# Using jQuery Mask and blank is being posted to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery mask functionality (specifically phone).  I am not doing any client side validation at this time and would like it to send over numbers even if they don't fill out the mask completely.

For example I am expecting to get 10 digits for a phone number.  If the user only puts in 9 I want my server to handle the error.  Unfortunately if the entered value does not match the mask it will send nothing.

Here is my js code:

```
   $(".phone input[type=text]").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

What do I need to do so that even if the mask is not filled out it will still send the value when the form is posted?

Comment: Is mask a JQuery function or are you using some JQuery plugin or another library?

Comment: @Erick The OP is presumably using [this masking plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). Here is [a basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/m689v1jd/) I just created; the value seems to include the masked portion on submit, so I'm not able to reproduce the issue..

Comment: I am coming into this as the second developer but I believe that the pluging that is being used is this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation of the mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) that you're using, everything after a `?` is optional, therefore you could use the following in order to retain the value even if 10 digits aren't provided:

```
$(".phone input[type=text]").mask("?(999) 999-9999");
```

---

If you want to strip out the non-digit characters, you could use the following when retrieving the element's value:

```
$(".phone input[type=text]").val().replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

If you want to strip those characters out on submit, you would use something like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $(".phone input[type=text]").val(function () {
    return this.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
  });
});
```

---

As a side note, if you use [this masking plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) instead, this wouldn't be a problem. In addition, it also has a `cleanVal()` method in order to remove the formatting characters.

Comment: I will try these tonight when I work on it again.  I was looking at using the optional value but I wanted to see if someone knew a better answer.  I may have to dump the value on blur because the plugin seems to blank it on its blur handler if it does not meet the mask requirements.